# creating button in android notification bar

Tags: android, eclipse, button, notifications

I have a dialog activity. I want to create a button in the notification that everywhere when we click on , my dialog activity will show and also user cannot cancel it. How can i do it?

sorry for my bad English.

thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use an "ongoing" notification:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)